# Direct download for Flash?

Tags: flash

I know about this: https://superuser.com/questions/60020/how-do-i-install-flash-player-10-without-adobe-download-manager
But the urls are completely outdated and simply don't work.

I've been surfing the web with Flash disabled for about 2 years now I think and it's getting better and better, but some websites still require you to have Flash enabled. And since new Flash vulnerabilities are pretty much found on a daily bases, I'm manually updating my Flash every time I'm using it.

Now you might say "Flash has a built in auto updater", to which I would reply "The auto updater updates my Flash about once a month (depending on how often I restart my PC and if I put it in hibernate) and when it actually auto updates, it doesn't install the latest version."

But the manual download process is really time consuming and annoying. I also have a really bad feeling running an adobe service in the background 24/7.

So is there still a simple direct download link for the Flash plugin for Firefox? Or maybe even better a link to the plugin file directly?